# Apache ProxyPass to Rack gives 404 error

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-404, rack, proxypass

(for simplicity I changed IPs of Apache server to 1.1.1.1 and Gollum server to 6.6.6.6)

I'm trying to serve a [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) wiki with rack through Apache (since it has SSL set up properly and I'm currently only testing the Gollum wiki). So I setup Apache to ProxyPass (config below).

The problem is that the rack server seems to be working fine when I access it directly via a curl from my proxy machine:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [05/Dec/2013 06:20:25] "GET /docs/Home HTTP/1.1" 200 6467 0.2135
```

but I get a 404 whenever I  try to use my browser. Rackup says:

```
6.6.6.6 - - [05/Dec/2013 06:20:00] "GET /docs/Home HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0006
```

Absurdly, when I use the *exact* same headers as my browser sends (see below) via telnet from the proxy machine (1.1.1.1) the request is successful:

```
6.6.6.6 - - [05/Dec/2013 06:19:19] "GET /docs/Home HTTP/1.1" 200 6467 0.2759
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and why (and how?!) rack differentiates between two different requests from the same machine. Help please?

(Using Apache/2.2.15 on RHEL 5 and Rack 1.2 (Release: 1.5) on ruby 1.9.2p320, RHEL 6)

**EDIT** Apparently this is a problem with WEBrick, since when I switch to Thin it worked. Would still like your insights...

---

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>

    ServerName testserver.example.org
    ServerAlias testserver.example.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org

    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/docs
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

    # ...

    <Location /docs/>
        ProxyPass http://6.6.6.6:8080/docs/

        # also tried:
        # ProxyPass http://rackserver.example.org:8080/docs/

        # and:
        # SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
        # SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

---

Telnetted request:

```
<1>root@testserver:~$ telnet rackserver.example.org 8080
Trying 6.6.6.6...
Connected to rackserver.example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /docs/Home HTTP/1.1
ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch
ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0
COOKIE: SESS...; has_js=1
HOST: rackserver.example.org:8080
USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
VERSION: HTTP/1.1
X_FORWARDED_FOR: 6.6.6.6
X_FORWARDED_HOST: apacheserver.example.org
X_FORWARDED_SERVER: testserver.example.org
```

I verified that the rack up prints the same output for the normal browser request and the telnetted request using [the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317705/rackrequest-how-do-i-get-all-headers).